# JDO owned one-to-many child entity not persisted

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I'm trying to persist a child entity in a bi-directional one-to-many owned relationship in GAE with JDO, following the way described in https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-java/KNnDuZ3yXkM, which says the new child need simply be added to the parent object's "children list" member as part of a transaction. However, my child object is not persisted in the datastore.

I'm using GWT 2.5.1, google appengine 1.8.0, trying things in development mode mostly.

My parent class is UserData, the child class is Category2.
Here is the relevant parts of the parent class:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class UserData implements IsSerializable {
    @NotPersistent
    public static final int CURRENT_EPOCH = 1;

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long key;

    @Persistent(mappedBy = "userData")
    @Order(extensions = @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus",
                key="list-ordering", value="category asc"))
    public List<Category2> categories;

    ...

    public UserData() {
        this.categories = new LinkedList<Category2>();
        ...
    }
}
```

and the child class:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class Category2 implements IsSerializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    private String key;
    @Persistent
    private UserData userData;

    @Persistent
    private String category;
    @Persistent
    private String subcategory;
    @Persistent
    private boolean obsolete;

    public Category2() {
    }

    public Category2(String cat, String subcat, boolean obsolete) {
        this.category = cat;
        this.subcategory = subcat;
        this.obsolete = obsolete;
    }
    ...
}
```

Code I'm executing is this:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

// Get the UserData object for this user
UserData userData;
Query q = pm.newQuery(UserData.class);
List<UserData> list = (List<UserData>) q.execute();
if (list.size() == 1) {
    userData = list.get(0);
} else {
    throw new BasileException("Found " + list.size() +
            " UserData objects");
}

Category2 cat = new Category2("MyCat", "MySubcat", false);
LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Adding category. Current num cats: " + 
        userData.categories.size());
Transaction tx = null;
tx = pm.currentTransaction();
try {
    tx.begin();
    q = pm.newQuery(Category2.class,
            "category == cat && subcategory == subcat");
    q.declareParameters("String cat, String subcat");
    List<Category2> cats = (List<Category2>) q.execute(
            cat.getCategory(), cat.getSubcategory());
    assert(cats.size() <= 1);
    if (cats.size() == 1)
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Category " + cat + " already exists!");
    else
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Category did not exist");

    userData.categories.add(cat);
    tx.commit();
    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Num cats now: " + userData.categories.size());
} finally {
    if (tx.isActive()) {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Transaction aborted!");
        tx.rollback();
    }
    pm.close();
}
```

The output I get every time I run the code (in GWT devmode) is this:

```
[java] 05-Jun-2013 14:31:41 com.appspot.basileexp.server.BasileServiceImpl2 runRepro
[java] INFO: Adding category. Current num cats: 0
[java] 05-Jun-2013 14:31:42 com.appspot.basileexp.server.BasileServiceImpl2 runRepro
[java] INFO: Category did not exist
[java] 05-Jun-2013 14:31:42 com.appspot.basileexp.server.BasileServiceImpl2 runRepro
[java] INFO: Num cats now: 1
```

and checking the datastore in the admin console shows that no Category2 entities are present in the datastore.

Here's my jdoconfig.xml just in case:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig">
      <persistence-manager-factory name="xg-transactions">
        <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass" value="org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>
      </persistence-manager-factory>
    </jdoconfig>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Firstly using old version of GAE JDO ... v2.1.2 is the latest and you're using ancient v1.x. Secondly the log (at DEBUG level) is what you should use to debug

Comment: Well, I'm using appengine-java-sdk-1.8.0 out of the box, which appears to have JDO v2.1.2, at least according to the RELEASE_NOTES.ORM file. I reran my test with logging.level=ALL, and see this, which doesn't tell me much:
`[java] 05-Jun-2013 20:04:55 org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl performReachabilityAtCommit`
`[java] FINE: Performing check of objects for "persistence-by-reachability" (commit) ...`
`[java] 05-Jun-2013 20:04:55 org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl performReachabilityAtCommit`
`[java] FINE: Completed check of objects for "persistence-by-reachability" (commit).`

Comment: it has 2.1.2 ... as an option; you haven't selected it based on your jdoconfig.xml.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, let me try that - thanks for your responses!

Comment: I upgraded to GAE JDO 2.1.2 but now I'm getting a NullPointerException whose stack trace contains `org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.PersistableMapping.postInsert(PersistableMapping.java:759)` down to `org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:756)`. Not sure if it's related to my original problem or if I should perhaps post a separate question here. Googling suggests this might be a bug with 1-1 bi-directional relationships (http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2274) but it's not clear whether it was fixed since or not...

Comment: Indeed, if I remove the 1-1 member (which I omitted in the code above because it seemed irrelevant) from the parent entity, everything starts working and the children are persisted. Therefore, it looks like outdated GAE JDO was the problem in my original question.